# Remove out of order column data in csv when array key-value pair is missing

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, export-to-csv

I have a multidimensional array in which some arrays are missing a key-value pair that is found in the other arrays. When I convert to csv (in this case, tab-delimited), the column cells in a row shift to the left and replace the missing key/value. For example, this array:

```
array
  (
  array("Make" => "Volvo", "Color" => "red", "Quantity" => 18),
  array("Make" => "BMW", "Color" => "blue", "Quantity" => 13),
  array("Make" => "Saab", "Quantity" => 11),
  array("Make" => "Land Rover", "Color" => "green", "Quantity" => 15)
  );
```

**VERSION 1**

When I use the following code:

```
$cfilename = 'result.csv';
$data = array
  (
  array("Make" => "Volvo", "Color" => "red", "Quantity" => 18),
  array("Make" => "BMW", "Color" => "blue", "Quantity" => 13),
  array("Make" => "Saab", "Quantity" => 11),
  array("Make" => "Land Rover", "Color" => "green", "Quantity" => 15)
  );

    //below creates csv
$fp = fopen($cfilename, 'w');
$header = false;
foreach ($data as $row)
{

fputcsv($fp, $row, chr(9));
}
fclose($fp);
return;
```

Will give me output like this:

```
Volvo      |red    | 18
BMW        |blue   | 13
Saab       |11     | 
Land Rover |green  | 15
```

I can get the columns to line up correctly if I use the key labels to write the headers. But in this case, instead of the cell for the missing key/value pair being empty, the column number is printed in it's place.

**VERSION 2**
This code:

```
$cfilename = 'result.csv';
$data = array
  (
  array("Make" => "Volvo", "Color" => "red", "Quantity" => 18),
  array("Make" => "BMW", "Color" => "blue", "Quantity" => 13),
  array("Make" => "Saab", "Quantity" => 11),
  array("Make" => "Land Rover", "Color" => "green", "Quantity" => 15)
  );

//below creates csv
$fp = fopen($cfilename, 'w');
$header = false;
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    if (empty($header)) //creates header, chr(9) makes tab delimited
    {
        $header = array_keys($row);
        fputcsv($fp, $header, chr(9));
        $header = array_flip($header);
    }
    fputcsv($fp, array_merge($header, $row), chr(9)); //creates rows, chr(9) makes tab delimited
}
fclose($fp);
return;
```

Results in this:

```
Make       | Color | Quantity
-----------|-------|----
Volvo      |red    | 18
BMW        |blue   | 13
Saab       |1      | 11
Land Rover | green | 15
```

Note, the "1" under color in the "Saab" row.

Getting either version to work would be great, if it's version 1, without the headings, I can always add that line into the tab-delimited output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is `1` because that's the value in the `$header` array for the Color key (you flipped it before merging it, so instead of being `1 => "Color"`, now it's `"Color" => 1`). What you can do to get rid of this is setting all values to NULL, or an empty string, or a placeholder, or whatever you want to be there when there's no value, with `array_map()`:

```
<?php
$cfilename = 'result.csv';
$data = array
  (
  array("Make" => "Volvo", "Color" => "red", "Quantity" => 18),
  array("Make" => "BMW", "Color" => "blue", "Quantity" => 13),
  array("Make" => "Saab", "Quantity" => 11),
  array("Make" => "Land Rover", "Color" => "green", "Quantity" => 15)
  );
echo "<pre>";
//below creates csv
$fp = fopen($cfilename, 'w');
$header = false;
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    if (empty($header)) //creates header, chr(9) makes tab delimited
    {
        $header = array_keys($row);
        fputcsv($fp, $header, chr(9));
        $header = array_flip($header);
        $header = array_map(function($header) { return "";}, $header);
    }
    // var_dump($header);
    fputcsv($fp, array_merge($header, $row), chr(9)); //creates rows, chr(9) makes tab delimited

}
fclose($fp);
return;
```

[Demo (without saving to file, only printing to screen)](https://3v4l.org/fQ4Hm)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set the field to an empty string if it doesn't exist?

```
$cfilename = 'result.csv';
$data = array(
    array("Make" => "Volvo", "Color" => "red", "Quantity" => 18),
    array("Make" => "BMW", "Color" => "blue", "Quantity" => 13),
    array("Make" => "Saab", "Quantity" => 11),
    array("Make" => "Land Rover", "Color" => "green", "Quantity" => 15)
);

//below creates csv
$fp = fopen($cfilename, 'w');
$header = false;
$fields = ['Make', 'Color', 'Quantity'];
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    foreach($fields as $field) {
        if (!array_key_exists($field, $row) {
            $row[$field] = '';
        }
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $row, chr(9));
}
fclose($fp);
return;
```